# How do we connect a camera using a Raspberry Pi 2 to an iPhone?

Tags: pi-2

How do we connect a camera to a raspberry pi 2 that connects to an iPhone over live video?
We are willing to buy any camera that is necessary.

Comment: have you googled "live stream video RPI".........

Comment: the hardware is almost irrelevant - any rpi camera will provide the video - it's the software side you want to investigate